# QWebFrame::findAllElements() doesn’t work in separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I'm trying to parse webPage to get all links on it. I use a QThreadPool and my own class implementing QRunnable, which provides all functionality. Everything is going good, if I run such QRunnable in main thread, but when I put my Runnable to the thread pool, QWebFrame::findAllElements(“a”) returns empty set. =(

I run my Runnable:
in same thread, findAllElements() works perfect

```
webLoader()->run();
```

findAllElements() returns empty set =(

```
threadPool->start(webLoader);
```

I've already spent many hours trying to figure out problem. =(

Here is my code snippets:

```
webloader.h

class WebLoader : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QUrl url;
    QString textPattern;
    QWebPage* page;
public:
    explicit WebLoader(const QUrl& url, const QString& textPattern);
    void run();
    virtual ~WebLoader();
signals:
    void loaded(QList<QUrl> urls, bool error, bool found);
private slots:
    void loadFinished(bool success);
};


webloader.cpp

WebLoader::WebLoader(const QUrl& url, const QString& textPattern): url(url),     textPattern(textPattern) {
    setAutoDelete(false);
}

void WebLoader::run() {
    QEventLoop loop;

    page = new QWebPage;
    page->mainFrame()->load(url);

    connect(page->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
    connect(page->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    loop.exec(); 
}

void WebLoader::loadFinished(bool success) {
    QList<QUrl> urlList;
    bool found = false;

    if(success) {
        QWebElementCollection collection = page->mainFrame()->findAllElements("a");

        foreach(QWebElement element, collection) {
            if(element.hasAttribute("href")) {
                urlList.push_back(url.resolved(QUrl(element.attribute("href"))));
            }
        }

        found = page->findText(textPattern);
    }

    emit loaded(urlList, !success, found);
}
```

PS. sorry for my English.

Comment: You can't use QtWebKit APIs in any threads but the main thread.

Comment: @peppe Wow, such a interesting detail. Can you give me a link to the documentation, where such rule is described? And what is a reason for such a strict constraint?

Comment: For instance [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread): "The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads". QtWebKit classes are amongst those. Moreover, notice that QWebPage, QWebElement etc. classes documentation doesn't say that [they're reentrant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/threads-reentrancy.html). So you must assume you can only use them from ONE thread only: the GUI thread.